# ggplot2 animation shows some empty plots

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot a lot of scatterplots in an animation, but a lot of the plots show just an empty plot. It also differs everytime I run the code/adjust the range.
Some plots do work and they are all supposed to look like this:
[image: plot1]

But most of the plots look like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(animation)

begintime <- min(dfL$time)
endtime <- max(dfL$time)
beginRange <- begintime
endRange <- begintime + 10

dateRangeBetween <- function(x,y){dfL[dfL$time >= x & dfL$time <= y,]}

saveHTML({
  for (i in 1:20) {
    dfSub <- dateRangeBetween(beginRange, endRange)
    ggScatterplot = ggplot(data = dfSub, aes(x = UTM_WGS84.Longitude, y = UTM_WGS84.Latitude)) + ggtitle("Coordinates") + xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") + theme(legend.position = "top") + geom_point()

    beginRange <- beginRange + 10
    endRange <- endRange + 10
    print(ggScatterplot)
  }
}, img.name = "coordinatesplots", imgdir = "coordinatesplots", htmlfile = "coordinatesplots.html", 
outdir = getwd(), autobrowse = FALSE, ani.height = 400, ani.width = 600, 
verbose = FALSE, autoplay = TRUE, title = "Coordinates")
```

This is an example of my dataframe:

```
    track                    time UTM_WGS84.Longitude UTM_WGS84.Latitude
1       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.711            5.481687           51.43635
2       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.717            5.481689           51.43635
3       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.723            5.481689           51.43635
4       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.730            5.481690           51.43635
5       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.763            5.481691           51.43635
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for your plots being empty is that the subset of your data.frame itself is empty.

I think (hard to say without seeing your full data) that your problem is that you're not incrementing by the correct amount of time. By default, adding a number to a date will add a number of seconds. I suspect the full range of your data is less than 10 seconds, and therefore only the first plot will show some data. After that the time range will be outside of the range of your data.

If that is the case, just change the `+ 10` to the actual amount of time you want to add. 1: 1 second, 0.1: a tenth of a second, etc...

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that's not the case. The data is much bigger and I've tried a different number of steps. Sometimes only the first ones work and sometimes a couple of plots in the middle work, or both/nothing. So it's really random.

Comment: What is the total time interval of your data?

Comment: For the set of data I'm using right now it's 15 minutes

Comment: Running your exact code with data generated like this: 

`startDate <- ymd_hms('2015-10-14 23:59:55.711');`
`dfL <- data.frame(time=seq(startDate,  startDate + 15 * 60, 
                           length.out=100000), 
                  UTM_WGS84.Longitude=runif(100000), 
                  UTM_WGS84.Latitude=runif(100000))`


produces a set of non-empty plots. 
I could see a number of potential issues related to R's scoping. Are you running the code exactly like this? Or part of it in a function?

Comment: Yes I'm running the code exactly like this. What do you think makes the difference with your code then?

Comment: You can try running your code with the generated data I showed you. If it works, then it is something with your own data. Maybe there's a gap in the time column?

Comment: Your example does work, thank you. Now I just have to figure out why my data wouldn't work.. Thanks for helping.